# How we can disable merge of a pull request in github if any check fails in the CI job

Tags: github, github-actions

We have a Jenkins CI job, where we will run a job when a pull request is raised. If that job fails in any case, we should not allow the user to merge the pull request. Is there any way we can do using github actions?

Comment: What do you mean "using GitHub actions"? You want to migrate the CI job over *instead of* using Jenkins? If you want the build status from Jenkins for e.g. branch protection rules, use https://plugins.jenkins.io/github/.

Comment: Yes @jonrsharpe i got it, In my case we can't use github actions. we can use only if we dont have an external CI system. So I have used branch protection rules. Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could:

- enable to branch protection policy "[Require status checks to pass before merging](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/administering-a-repository/enabling-required-status-checks)"
- Follow the "[Creating CI tests with the Checks API](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/developers/apps/creating-ci-tests-with-the-checks-api)" guide, which does not require a GitHub Action, and can create "[Check runs and requested actions](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest/guides/getting-started-with-the-checks-api#check-runs-and-requested-actions)".
  Using checks (as [I mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51751236/6309)) would be a good way to prevent any merge while the PR has any check with an associated "failed" status.

The [OP Ramanichandran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9444179/ramanichandran) confirms [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65580689/how-we-can-disable-merge-of-a-pull-request-in-github-if-any-check-fails-in-the-c/65580859?noredirect=1#comment116135870_65580859) it is working:

> For each failure stage in jenkins, we call this github api

```
sh('curl "https://api.github.com/repos/reponame/statuses/$GIT_COMMIT?access_token=xxx" \ 
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \ 
-X POST \ 
-d "{\\\"state\\\": \\\"failure\\\", \\\"target_url\\\": \\\"https://jenkinsurl/job/foldername/job/jobname/$BUILD_NUMBER/console\\\", \\\"description\\\": \\\"Jenkins-CI-pre-merge-job-sonarscan-failure\\\", \\\"context\\\": \\\"Jenkins-CI-pre-merge-job-sonarscan-failure\\\"}"') } –
```

Comment: Thanks Vonc, I followed the branch protection policy step which you suggested. But it allows us to select only the status check found in the last week of the repository. Suppose if we dont have any failed status check found in the last week, how we can restrict the merging

Comment: @Ramanichandran Not sure, since I believe you should be able to set the status through API calls, regardless of its date. Did you find a way to make it work? (since you have accepted my answer since your comment)

Comment: Yes @Vonc, I have checked and implemented that,  it is working properly thanks for your help

Comment: @Ramanichandran Great! But *how* did you implement that? Any future user readong this page would want to know that.

Comment: For each failure stage in jenkins, we call this github api  sh('curl "https://api.GitHub.com/repos/reponame/statuses/$GIT_COMMIT?access_token=xxx" \
         -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
        -X POST \
        -d "{\\\"state\\\": \\\"failure\\\", \\\"target_url\\\": \\\"https://jenkinsurl/job/foldername/job/jobname/$BUILD_NUMBER/console\\\", \\\"description\\\": \\\"Jenkins-CI-pre-merge-job-sonarscan-failure\\\", \\\"context\\\": \\\"Jenkins-CI-pre-merge-job-sonarscan-failure\\\"}"')

                }

Comment: @Ramanichandran Thank you for the feedback, very useful indeed. I have edited the answer to include your comment, for more visibility.